# Sample random row from df.groupby("column1")["column2].max() and not first one if multiple candidates

Tags: pandas, random, group-by, max

What would be the correct way to return n random max values from a groupby?

I have a dataframe containing audio events, with the following columns:

- audio
- start_time
- end_time
- duration
- labelling confidence (1 to 5)
- label ("Ambulance", "Engine", ...)

I have multiple events/rows for each label and I have 26 labels in total.

What I would like to achieve is to get one event per label with max confidence.

Let's say we have 7 events that have label "Ambulance" and they have the following labelling confidence: 2, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 5.

The max confidence is 5 in this case, which gives us 3 selectable events.
I would like to get one of the three at random.

Doing the following with pandas: **df.groupby("label").max()** will return the first row with max labelling confidence. I would like it to be a random selection.

Many thanks in advance

Cheers

Antoine

Comment: Your title doesn't quite match the description and you didn't provide a [mcve] so I put this `df[df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('max').eq(df['B'])].groupby('A').sample()`. A is "label", B is "confidence". If this works and you deem necessary I can ramble on what it does. Or you can execute each part

Comment: Hi Neither,

Thank you for taking the time to reply.

I didn't add a minimal reproducible example because it is not a bug and providing the explanation of what I want to acheive together with the code I tried (df.groupby("label").max()) seemed enough to me.

As for the title, it is difficult to put it simply.

Thanks anyway for your suggestion. I tried it but it doesn't seem to work on my end unfortunately.

df[df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('max').eq(df['B'])] returns an empty dataframe.

The code suggestion from @Code Different below seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I finally managed to do it:

**shuffled_df = df.sample(frac=1)**

**filtered_df = shuffled_df.loc[shuffled_df.groupby("label")["confidence"].idxmax()]**

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** following a comment from the OP, the simplest solution is to shuffle the data frame before picking the max rows:

```py
# Some random data
labels = list('ABCDE')
repeats = np.random.randint(1, 6, len(labels))

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'label': np.repeat(labels, repeats),
    'confidence': np.random.randint(1, 6, repeats.sum())
})

# Shuffle the data frame. For each `label` get the first row,
# which we can be sure has the max `confidence` because we
# sorted it
(
    df.sample(frac=1)
      .sort_values(['label', 'confidence'], ascending=[True, False])
      .groupby('label')
      .head(1)
)
```

If you are running this in IPython / Jupyter Notebook, watch the index of the resulting data frame to see the randomness of the result.

Comment: Hi Code Different,

Thanks for taking the time to reply!
It seems to work. I didn't think about doing it this way.

Extending on what you suggest, I went on to dig further in that direction and there seems to be a faster and more concise way with the simple statement: **df.sample(frac=1)**

If shuffles the entire dataframe, without needing to add another column.
I think it does what I want.

Cheers

Antoine

Comment: Yes you are right. I didn't think about `sample`. Will edit my answer

Comment: Where does maximum play its role here?

Comment: You are right. I missed the `sort_values` call. Added

Comment: I tried your suggestion Code Different and it seems to not do what I want.
It returns a dataframe with one row with max confidence for each distinct label.
But running it several times always returns the same rows.
Please check my suggestion to my own post.
It does what I want.

Comment: Please check my edited answer